# Purge or call action to reset states?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-persist, redux-offline

My application is using the [redux-offline](https://github.com/redux-offline/redux-offline) package which has the ability to persist store. I came across this concept `purge` which seems to reset states upon loading app.

My apps have a sign out function in which it makes sense to clean the localStorage/cache. I'm wondering if in this case I should use the purge concept or create an action that resets all reducers instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `redux-offline` uses [`redux-persist`](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/tree/v4) under the hood to retain the `redux state` into the `storage`.

But there may be a case where you are blacklisting some reducers.

```
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: storage,
  blacklist: ['// Any such blacklisted reducer']
};
```

Therefore `.purge` method would be useful in such a case where you just want to **reset state stored in the disk** but not completely reset the **reducer state**.